# Making VOIP Calls Using 3G Network in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, voip

I am using linphone and siphon source code to make VOIP calls in iOS.

When I am using a wifi connection it is working fine, but when I make a call using 3g connection it is not audible.

Please guide me how to make it audible when it is connected with 3g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developer agreement forbids the development of VoIP software for 3G/Edge. Moreover, several mobile phone operator forbid the VoIP traffic on their 3G/EDGE network.

Comment: Hi Nitin Thanks for your answer but some apps are making calls using 3g Connection Eg:https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/dial91-voip/id445578908?mt=8 and once again thanks for your information

Comment: Only some operators forbid the VoIP Traffic while using linphone and siphon. See their document http://www.linphone.org/eng/blog/linphone-over-3g.html

Comment: I have both the apps linphone and dial91 but in linphone audio is not audible in 3g connection but dial91 is working fine.